# Why does floating allow for explicit width on an inline element?

Tags: css

I was unable set the width for an inline element `<span>` while creating a table-row with multiple span elements. I was able to modify the width once I put a `float: left` as well.

Why was I not able to set the width and height of inline elements? How does adding a float change things?

Answer (score 2):

[Inline elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements) by definition do not take explicit width or height but are *inline* and conform to the surrounding elements. They only occupy space bounded by the tags. For example:

```
This is some <span>text</span>
```

`<span>text</span>` only occupies the space that houses `text`. It's *in* the same *line* with the other text nodes in the HTML.

[The `float` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) implies block layout and the `display` property of elements is changed to block (in most cases) thus making them [block-level  elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) where you can set explicit width and height because they occupy all of their container. Per the MDN documentation:

> As `float` implies the use of the block layout, it modifies the computed value of the `display` values, in some cases

In this case, the table (viewable at the MDN documentation) shows that any elements with `display: table-row` would blockified and have `display: block` when floated.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer A**:

You can't explicitly set the width of an inline element because it is **relative** to the **surrounding** elements, and thus is restricted by **their** widths.

**Answer B**:

Floating an element with **[float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/float)** automatically makes it into a [**block-level element**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) by applying `display: block` to it. A block-level element occupies the entire space of its parent element (container), thereby creating a 'block'.

Hope this helps! :)